# Is it possible to upload media with a static url in Umbraco?

Tags: umbraco

Whenever we upload a media file to our Umbraco CMS, it generates a unique media id in the filename. So a file like `example.jpg` will be given a url like:

```
http://content.example.com/media/947/example.jpg
```

And if we update the file, it gets a new media id.

This is incredibly annoying, because there's no way to make a permalink to the image! We want to be able to create links to image files that non-technical people upload, but having a random and possibly changing id in the url means that any such link is in danger of breaking without warning.

So, is there any way to upload media files to Umbraco and have them placed in a **static** location?

Answer (score 4):

First of all, we need to think: **for what we want to use it?** If it will be used inside the currently developed website and needs to be managable, I don't see any reasons why current url convention or anything else with media may be considered as a blocker / barrier. It just requires to enable editors to select media in document types properties (in proper way e.g. using MediaPicker, MultiNodeTreePicker etc.) and while it's processed and rendered we can easily grab the URL of the file having media id and put this anywhere in the HTML markup. Ba! It's even better in my opinion, cause when we delete or re-upload the file, we don't need to change anything else inside the code or markup or logic, cause ID of the media file is not changing and we're still able to use it.

I don't know if any CMS enables users to be responsible of media files URLs creation... But if this is a case, basically, there is a way (or even more than one) to achieve this:

1. **"Hacky way"** - "File" document type and template returning data

You can create new document type with *MediaPicker* property inside of it. Then create and assign template with C# / Razor logic (depending if you want to e.g. hijack the route with custom controller or just render or return file inside the template) and just return file data in your desired way. If you want to display image - you can render it, if you want to play the audio or video - you can return proper objects / html5 tags or anything else. It may be a long switch statement covering all of the allowed file types and methods of returning them to user. You can also process the file and return it in HttpResponse to force browser to send file and user to download the file to his disk. Tricky one.

2. **"Umbraco advanced dev way"** - Custom *FileSystemProvider*

We can create custom **FileSystemProvider** and assign it to be used in MediaFileSystem. It can swap whole media workflow of retrieving and adressing the media. To be honest, I wasn't playing with this too much, but there is open-source project of media provider which stores media on Azure Blobs (https://our.umbraco.org/projects/collaboration/umbracofilesystemprovidersazure/) so we can preview how it's done there and adopt to our own scenario.

More info about custom FileSystemProvider: https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/extending/custom-file-systems.

3. **"Not recommended way"** - Duplicating files in custom directory during MediaService save event

It's the worst solution from the above in my opinion, as it removes all the great features which Umbraco gives us "out of box" for managing and processing media files (e.g. ImageCropper), but... we're able to hook up into MediaService events (https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/reference/events/mediaservice-events) and do whatever we want with file(s) uploaded to our site. It means that we're also able to duplicate files and place them to our custom directory which needs to be adopted and adjusted to be visible and used "from the outside".

So, as you can see - everything is possible :) But, getting back to the beggining of this long post - we need to think for what we want to use it and if we really need it. I still can't find any use case where I needed cool, awesome, custom media file IDs. If I would need them, I will use any url shorteners e.g. bit.ly, for campaing or anything else what will also give me a great analyze tool providing me data about number of downloads for example.

Comment: Our main problem with the media id is that there's no way to know it in advance. So suppose we ask our designer to upload 100 specific files to Umbraco. Each follows a naming convention like `example_{type}_{kind}.jpg`, where `type` runs from 1 to 25 and `kind` runs from 1 to 4 (thus 100 total). In *an external application* we need to link to those files. But instead of being able to link to a file with a known url like `/media/example_13_3.jpg`, we'd have to get the list of 100 random media id's that Umbraco generated, and keep in sync with these random numbers forever. That's a nightmare.

Comment: I would probably use FTP for this kind of scenario, rather than CMS, but it may be an option to just group those items in folders and map / select folder for item or page on which they should be displayed and then loop just through the content of assigned folder. Need to know the bigger picture for sure, but there is always a way! :)

Comment: @MarcinZajkowski for the "Hacky Way", where did you learn about this? Is there online documentation that shows this in action so that developers can try to mimic the scenario on their end? I need to see what this means. Thanks in advance for any sources.

Comment: @blackhawk I haven't done it, but my experience with Umbraco tells me it's possible and definitely, this is not a solution which might be covered anywhere in the documentation :) But still - it's pretty simple solution at the end. What I suggested is to fake file path with document types and Umbraco content structure. Each time when you're creating node in the content tree, you have URL associated with it. And your Razor template can do whatever you can with it - it's C#. So you can return http response with file too.